# Anorm 2.3 multi-value parameter: required anorm.NamedParameter

Tags: scala, anorm, playframework-2.3

Using scala 2.11.1 on play framework 2.3.

Because Anorm didn't support multi-value parameters in previous versions I used [David's](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/meYkd-KKQRE) workaround. Anorm now [supports](http://applicius-en.tumblr.com/post/87829484643/anorm-whats-new-play-2-3) [multi-value parameters](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAnorm) and I started removing the workaround and using Anorm multi-value parameters.

The [example](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/9a134eeecb441ae295632ecfc68b53ec1877c9a2) [sic] mentioned:

```scala
// With default formatting (", " as separator)
SQL("SELECT * FROM Test WHERE cat IN ({categories})").
  on('categories -> Seq("a", "b", "c")
// -> SELECT * FROM Test WHERE cat IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Yet my code:

```scala
val names = List("Able", "Baker", "Charlie") // Passed as a parameter to my method!
val result =
  SQL( """
    SELECT city
    FROM addresses
    WHERE name IN ({names});
  """ ).on( 'names -> names ).as( scalar[String] * )
```

gives me this error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Symbol, List[String])
 required: anorm.NamedParameter
```

or

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Symbol, scala.collection.immutable.Seq[String])
 required: anorm.NamedParameter
```

depending if i try a list or sequence (or one of the [suggestions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/multi-value$20parameter/play-framework/bhYn1EARH4o/9pU56lDsMNkJ) to map it).

I'm no expert, by far, and I *think* it's missing some implicit conversion? Clueless to find out how/what/where. Tips/suggestions/solutions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Anorm document, you will see there is no multi-value example using List. Indeed that's on purpose as instance of `NamedParameter` is implemented only for `Seq[T]`.

Just updating your code to `val names = Seq("Able", "Baker", "Charlie")` make it valid (and compiles).

I would suggest to edit your code using Anorm interpolation:

```scala
val result = 
  SQL"SELECT city FROM addresses WHERE name IN ($names)" as scalar[String].*

// OR (if names won't change):
val result = SQL"""SELECT city FROM addresses
    WHERE name IN (${Seq("Able", "Baker", "Charlie")})""".
  as(scalar[String].*)
```

EDIT: *See changes in Anorm https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3257 (supports List)*

Comment: Afraid that didn't fix it. See my error, i already tried a Seq. Something i noticed: an example Seq(A,B,C) works, but if it isn't defined on forehand it doesn't. I get the parameter as a List and a toSeq didn't work. It seems that while typing this, I might have found the solution: val names:Seq[String] = theList.toSeq (have to add the :Seq[String]. Will edit again if that fixed it.

Comment: Which code do you try with `Seq`? Have you tried pasted samples? I can confirm you that all given examples are working with Anorm 2.3. What's important that is that the visible type of multivalue passed as parameter must be `Seq[String]`. If you let `val seq = List("a", "b")`, yes seq is instance of `Seq`, but visible type is `List`, and implicit (typeclass) there is not defined for `S <: Seq[T]` but strictly for `Seq[T]`.

Comment: From the original question: `found: (Symbol, scala.collection.immutable.Seq[String])`. That was because I tried converting my passed parameter List to a Seq. `val seq = List("a", "b").toSeq`. That gave me the error. I changed that to: `val seq: Seq[String] = List("a", "b").toSeq` and it worked! So i guess that was my error. Assuming the List[String] .toSeq would give me a Seq[String]. (Don't know much about S<:Set[T] I'm afraid. Will look it up. Is that the visible type?) Re: tried the pasted samples: they worked, that's how i noticed the difference between the List.toSeq and a Seq("a","b").

Comment: That's not because you see `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` in to debug that the visible type is `Seq`. It's `List`, as `List` keep string representation from its parent (`.toString`). As said, instance of `NamedParameter` is defined only for `Seq[T]`, which means your multivalue need to be declared as a `Seq[T]`, not a `List[T]` even if `List[T]` is a kind of `Seq[T]`: with this implicit resolution inheritance is not followed (on purpose). Would you mind accepting the answer, as it fixes the original question. Best regards.