# implicit value for slick.jdbc.SetParameter[List[Int]]

Tags: scala, slick

I have a raw slick query backed by PostgreSQL. I want to run a query like this: `select something from my_table where action in (1,2,3)` . Note that action is an `integer` field in `my_table`

I'm getting a compilation error in my method below:

> could not find implicit value for parameter e:
>   slick.jdbc.SetParameter[List[Int]]

```
def myMethod(actions: List[Int]]) {
 sql"""select something from my_table 
        where action in (${actions})""".as[MyType]
}
```

**Question**

How can I explicitly set the `List[Int]` parameter so that I can successfully run the `in` query?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def myMethod(actions: List[Int]) =
  sql"""select something from my_table
        where action in #${actions.mkString("(", ",", ")")}""".as[MyType]
```

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/sql.html#splicing-literal-values

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: is there a type-safer way? as in anorm... https://stackoverflow.com/a/21277906/280393

Answer (score 1):

Use he slick-postgreSQL extensions:
https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg

more info:
[How to pass an array to a slick SQL plain query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306080/how-to-pass-an-array-to-a-slick-sql-plain-query/58306407#58306407)

```
implicit val setIntArray: SetParameter[Array[Int]] = mkArraySetParameter[Int](...)
```